# How to toggle two divs and change the height of divs to catch full size of main div

Tags: javascript, css, html, jquery

I have two child `DIV`s contained within a parent `DIV`.

Normally, the first child is 30% of the height of the parent and the second child is 70%

When a certain icon is clicked, the second child should expand to fill 100% of the height of the parent.

How can I implement this with jQuery?  Could I use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) for this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
$('.leftContainer .smallPicture').click(function(){
    $('.rightContainer').css('height', $('.mainDiv').height()+'px')
});
```

I've used the height in pixels because using height in percentage is sometimes a little problematic.

Comment: Side note: You don't need `+"px"` in jQuery.